# VueJS 2: Catch event of direct child component

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling, vue-component, vue.js

I'm currently trying to get a simple Tabs/Tab component up and running.
It seems like something in the event handling mechanism has changed, therefore I can't get it to work.

Current implementation:

**Tabs.vue**

```
<template>
    <div class="tabbed-pane">
        <ul class="tab-list">
            <li class="tab" v-for="tab in tabs" @click="activateTab(tab)">{{ tab.header }}</li>
        </ul>
        <slot></slot>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    import hub from '../eventhub';
    export default {
        props: [],
        data() {
            return  {
                tabs: []
            }
        },
        created() {
            this.$on('tabcreated', this.registerTab)
        },
        methods: {
            registerTab(tab) {
                this.tabs.push(tab);
            },
            activateTab(tab) {

            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

**Tab.vue**

```
<template>
    <div class="tab-pane" v-show="active">
        <slot></slot>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    import hub from '../eventhub';
    export default {
        props: {
            'header': String
        },
        data() {
            return {
                active: false
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            this.$emit('tabcreated', this);
        }
    }
</script>
```

**eventhub.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue';

export default new Vue();
```

**View**

```
<tabs>
    <tab header="Test">
        First Tab
    </tab>
    <tab header="Test2">
        Second Tab
    </tab>
    <tab header="Test3">
        Third Tab
    </tab>
</tabs>
```

I've tried the following things:

- use a Timeout for the `$emit` to test if it's a timing issue (it is
  not)
- use @tabcreated in the root element of the `Tabs` components
  template

It works if...

- ... I use the suggested "eventhub" feature (replacing `this.$on` and
  `this.$emit` with `hub.$on` and `hub.$emit`)

but this is not suitable for me, as I want to use the `Tabs` component multiple times on the same page, and doing it with the "eventhub" feature wouldn't allow that.

- ... I use `this.$parent.$emit`

but this just feels weird and wrong.

The documentation states that it IS possible to listen for events triggered by `$emit` on direct child components
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#dispatch-and-broadcast-replaced

Does anyone have an Idea?

Answer (score 0):

You're right, in vue 2, there is no more $dispatch. $emit could work for a single component but it will be scoped to himself (`this`). The recommended solution is to use a global event manager, the `eventhub`.

the eventhub can be stored in the window object to be used anywhere without import, I like to declare in my main.js file like this:

```
window.bus = new Vue()
```

and then in whatever component:

```
bus.$emit(...)
bus.$on(...)
```

It works just the same as `this.$root.$emit` / `this.$root.$on`. You said it works when you call `this.$parent.$emit`, but this code, simulate a scoped emit in the parent component but fired from the child, not good.

What I understand in your code is that you want to have an array of created tabs, but to do what with them ?

Instead of storing the tab instance in the parent and then activate from the parent, you should think about a more functional way.
The `activateTab` method should be declared on the tab component and manage the instanciation through the `data`, something like:

### Tabs.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="tabbed-pane">
        <ul class="tab-list">
            <tab v-for="tab in tabs" :header="tab.header"></tab>
        </ul>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    import hub from '../eventhub';
    import Tab from 'path/to/Tab.vue';
    export default {
        components: [Tab],
        props: [],
        data() {
            return  {
                tabs: ['First Tab', 'Second Tab', 'Third Tab']
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

### Tab.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="tab tab-pane" @click:activeTab()>
        <span v-show="active">Activated</span>
        <span>{{ header }}</span>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    import hub from '../eventhub';
    export default {
        props: {
            'header': String
        },
        data() {
            return {
                active: false
            }
        },
        methods: {
            activeTab () {
               this.active = true
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

This way, your `Tab` is more independant. For parent/child communication keep this in mind :

- parent to child > via props
- child to parent > via $emit (global bus)

If you need a more complexe state management you definitely should take a look at [vuex](http://vuex.vuejs.org/en/intro.html).

---

#### Edit

### Tabs.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="tabbed-pane">
        <ul class="tab-list">
            <tab v-for="tabData in tabs" :custom="tabData"></tab>
        </ul>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    import Tab from 'path/to/Tab.vue';
    export default {
        components: [Tab],
        props: [],
        data() {
            return  {
                tabs: [
                  {foo: "foo 1"},
                  {foo: "foo 2"}
                  {foo: "foo 3"}
                ]
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

### Tab.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="tab tab-pane" @click:activeTab()>
        <span v-show="active">Activated</span>
        <span>{{ custom.foo }}</span>
    </div>
</template>
<script>

    export default {
        props: ['custom'],
        data() {
            return {
                active: false
            }
        },
        methods: {
            activeTab () {
               this.active = true
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Well, i need the Tab to contain more than just a Header ;) but well, I'll stick to the event bus and namespace the tabs

Comment: So you can pass an object or severals attributes to props. For exemple:

Tabs.vue
    <tab v-for="tab in tabs" :custom="tab"></tab>
    ...
    data() {
            return  {
                tabs: [{foo: "foo1", bar:"bar1"}, {foo: "foo2", bar:"bar2"}]
            }
        }

And in Tab.vue

Answer (score 0):

This is what I don't like about VueJS (2), there is **no convenient way of catching events emitted from child components to the parent component.**

Anyways an alternative to this is if you do not want to use the eventhub approach, specially if you are only going to have an event communication between related components ( child and parent ) and not with non-related components, then you can do these steps.

1. reference your parent vue component on its data property (very important, you can't just pass **this** to the child component)
2. pass that parent vue component reference as an attribute to the child component ( make sure to bind it)
3. trigger the appropriate event of the parent component inside the child component whenever a desired event is emitted

Pseudo code

```
// Parent vue component
Vue.component( 'parent_component' , {

   // various codes here ...

   data : {
      parent_component_ref : this // reference to the parent component
   },

   methods : {

      custom_event_cb : function() {
         // custom method to execute when child component emits 'custom_event'
      }

   }

   // various codes here ...

} );

// Parent component template
<div id="parent_component">
   <child_component :parent_component_ref="parent_component_ref"></child_component>
</div>

// Child component
Vue.component( 'child_component' , {

   // various codes here ...

   props : [ 'parent_component_ref' ],

   mounted : function() {

      this.$on( 'custom_event' , this.parent_component_ref.custom_event_cb );


      this.$emit( 'custom_event' );

   },

   // You can also, of course, emit the event on events inside the child component, ex. button click, etc..

} );
```

Hope this helps anyone.

Comment: I really prefer the event bus over this solution, as it's far cleaner. This is a hack you can consider, but is not at all how Vue is intended to be used

Comment: @FabianBettag As I have said above, this is an alternative for when you do not want the event bus style, specially if the communication is between the parent and child component only. Spare you from creating a separte vue instance.

Answer (score 0):

Use `v-on="$listeners"`, which is available since Vue `v2.4.0`. You can then subscribe to any event you want on the parent, see [fiddle](https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-KqoXc43ubNhc4Aun2YZ).

Credit to `BogdanL` from Vue Support @ Discord.